# How to make query that will return differences between two tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I need to return differences between two tables.

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE first(
  zoom smallint NOT NULL,
  x integer NOT NULL,
  y integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE second(
  zoom smallint NOT NULL,
  x integer NOT NULL,
  y integer NOT NULL
);
```

INSERT DATA

```
INSERT INTO first(zoom,x,y) VALUES(5,2,25);
INSERT INTO first(zoom,x,y) VALUES(5,4,45);
INSERT INTO first(zoom,x,y) VALUES(5,7,34);
INSERT INTO first(zoom,x,y) VALUES(5,45,40);
INSERT INTO first(zoom,x,y) VALUES(5,72,63);
INSERT INTO second(zoom,x,y) VALUES(5,2,25);
INSERT INTO second(zoom,x,y) VALUES(5,4,45);
INSERT INTO second(zoom,x,y) VALUES(5,7,34);
```

Wanted result:

```
In table first there are extra rows:
5,45,40
5,72,63
```

**Edit**

Sorry about this, but I have figured out now that my original data is pretty much complexed then the sample I provided. So in the original data, table first consists of 900 rows, and table second of 935 rows. I assumed that the rows are distinct in each table, however as I am not sure now, so  I would like to include this condition in a query. I assumed query would return 35 rows as difference, because I was pretty much convinced that all zoom/x/y would be same except this 35 one. However, it might now be the case. So basically what I need to know is what are differences between two tables, whatever approach is the best to solve it.

Can I get something like this:

```
 zoom | x  | y  | first |second
------+----+--- +-------+------
   5  | 45 | 40 |  yes  |  no |
```

order by first yes, second no

```
 zoom | x  | y  | first |second
------+----+--- +-------+------
   5  | 45 | 40 |  yes  |  no |
   5  | 45 | 40 |  yes  |  no |
   5  | 45 | 40 |  yes  |  no |
```

then first no, second yes

```
 zoom | x  | y  | first |second
------+----+--- +-------+------
   5  | 45 | 40 |  no   |  yes |
   5  | 45 | 40 |  no   |  yes |
   5  | 45 | 40 |  no   |  yes |
```

Comment: Are you interested just in the case of the example (rows that are in "first"  table but not in second) or also the opposite case?

Comment: After your "edit" : probably you should remove the last "first no, second no": if both the tables don't have the rows, where should the query take those rows?

Comment: @Insac Thanks about that

Comment: @Insac no thanks, was just keeping track. I guess the result must be 859 rows then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to compare all columns of both tables, you can use a full outer join on all columns and the check if one of them is:

```
select case 
          when f.zoom is null then 'missing in first'
          when s.zoom is null then 'missing in second'
       end as status, 
       zoom, x, y
from "first" f
  full outer join second s using (zoom, x, y)
where f.zoom is null or s.zoom is null;
```

The join based on `using()` will return those columns that are not null (and only those columns - removing the duplicate columns from the result)

When using your sample data from the question, the result would be:

```
status            | zoom | x  | y 
------------------+------+----+---
missing in second |    5 | 45 | 40
missing in second |    5 | 72 | 63
```

If a row in the second table is added that doesn't exist in the first, e.g.:

```
 INSERT INTO second(zoom,x,y) VALUES(15,7,34);
```

then the result will be:

```
status            | zoom | x  | y 
------------------+------+----+---
missing in second |    5 | 45 | 40
missing in second |    5 | 72 | 63
missing in first  |   15 |  7 | 34
```

Comment: This query returned me 859 rows.

Comment: Thanks very much! I have choosen this answer as correct one, because it returns results orderd by status!

Comment: @newbie_girl: that is pure coincidence as there is no `order by` in my query. If you need to be **sure** about the order you have to add an `order by`

Comment: Oh wow, sorry, havent seen that there is no order by, it just ended up to be in order then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`EXCEPT`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/sql-select.html)

```
select zoom,x,y from first 
except 
select zoom,x,y from second
```

or am missing something here

If you want non matching records from both the tables then

```
select * from
(
select zoom,x,y from first 
except 
select zoom,x,y from second
) a
union all
select * from 
(
select zoom,x,y from second
except 
select zoom,x,y from first 
) b
```

Comment: I answered as you yesterday to a similar question,  but the OP hasn't specified if the rows to be retrieved are only on "first"  table or if she's interested also in rows in "second"  table that are not in the first.

Comment: @Insac - *In table first there are extra rows:* so I guess OP is looking only in first table. Lets wait for OP to clarify

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look. So first query with EXCEPT would return me rows that are in table first but now in table second? Returned rows: 412.

Comment: Second query returns me everthing  that is in table first, and not second and it is in the table second and not first? Returned rows 859.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select max(which) as AppearsIn, x, y, zoom
from ((select 'first' as which, x, y, zoom from first) union all
      (select 'second', x, y, zoom from second)
     ) x
group by x, y, zoom
having count(*) = 1;
```

This assumes that the rows are distinct in each table.

Comment: Small thing: there is a `z zoom` instead of `zoom`

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question. This query returns me: 940 rows.

Comment: Ah! So this query will return: 859 rows. The previous comment will be deleted if I get the opportunity to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want possible duplicate mismatches, you should count them:

```
SELECT COALESCE(f.zoom,s.zoom) AS zoom
        , COALESCE(f.x,s.x) AS x
        , COALESCE(f.y,s.y) AS y
        , COALESCE(f.fcnt,0) AS fcnt
        , COALESCE(s.scnt,0) AS scnt
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT zoom,x,y
        , COUNT (*) AS fcnt
        FROM first
        GROUP BY zoom,x,y
        ) f
FULL OUTER JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT zoom,x,y
        , COUNT (*) AS scnt
        FROM second
        GROUP BY zoom,x,y
        ) s USING (zoom,x,y)
WHERE f.fcnt IS NULL OR s.scnt IS NULL
        ;
```